# Two fullscreen menus - how to show one and hide the other - using toggleclass

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using `jquery` `toggleclass` to show and hide a fullscreen menu. The problem arises because there are two fullscreen menus. If one is open, how do I hide it if the user clicks on the other one?

I'm guessing I need to toggle the show/hide class on both `divs`. So when one is 'show' the other is 'hide'. But how do I do this? I've worked out how to toggle a class on one `div`, but not two.

https://jsfiddle.net/facnr6f9/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".projects_link").click(function(){
  $(".projects_overlay").toggleClass("show_projects");
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".menu_link").click(function(){
  $(".menu_overlay").toggleClass("show_menu");
 });
});
```

```css
.projects_overlay {
display: none;
}
.show_projects {
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 7.2rem;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
background-color: pink;
}
.menu_overlay {
display: none;
}
.show_menu {
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 7.2rem;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<span class="projects_link">PROJECTS</span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="menu_link">MENU</span>
<div class="projects_overlay">
  <ul>
    <li>Project 1</li>
    <li>Project 2</li>
    <li>Project 3</li>
    <li>Project 4</li>
    <li>Project 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu_overlay">
  <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the class is removed from the other menu when one is selected.

For example:

```
$(".menu_link").click(function(){
    $(".projects_overlay").removeClass("show_projects");
    $(".menu_overlay").toggleClass("show_menu");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/facnr6f9/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a simple solution